# Disable horizontal scrolling in QScrollArea completely, not just the bars

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, scroll

In Qt, I have a QScrollArea that has some content in it that can scroll vertically but should never, ever be allowed to scroll horizontally. Even if I disable the H scrollbars from showing, a mouse that has a scroll wheel (or touch pad) that supports horizontal motion will make it move a little bit side to side.

Now, this may partly be a layout issue... but nothing is actually off the screen.
It's probably a cop-out, but is there a way to just "lock" the scroll area from behind able to move horizontally at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your `QScrollArea` you need filter `QEvent::Wheel` in `eventFilter` method or overload `wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event)` method.

Other way is create widget inherited from `QWidget` with overloaded `eventFilter` only and apply its filter to your scroll area:

```
scrollArea->viewport()->installEventFilter(someFilterWidget);
```

Answer (score 14):

```
scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setEnabled(false);
scrollArea->horizontalScrollBar()->setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Wow, this worked beautifully! So much simpler than overriding events. Disabling the vertical scrollbar through this method even allows the mouse scroll-wheel to move the horizontal scroll.

Comment: Can you help me understand the -> symbols? I am not sure how to use this solution in my code. Thank you.self.list_widget_left.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.list_widget_left.horizontalScrollBar.setEnabled(false)

Comment: @winteralfs, as this question is marked with C++ tag, the code is in C++. But this arrow '->' is equivalent to a dot '.' in Python.

self.scrollArea.horizontalScrollBar().setEnabled(False)

Comment: I would say this is a better candidate for an answer, though this question is now 9 years old. This is an excellent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the scroll bar policy ?

myScrollArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html#horizontalScrollBarPolicy-prop

Comment: Yes, I'm already doing that. All that does is hide the scroll bars. But you can still scroll with a mouse.